# Angular 5 create An array with from JSON data and sum values

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I am trying to create data to display in chart (2 lines), but I am having issues.

I have tried several reduce methods found here, but I was not able to do that.

My Json is :

```
{
  createdDate: "2017-11-17",
  doneDate: "2017-11-17",
},
{
  createdDate: "2017-11-17",
  doneDate: "2017-11-17",
},
{
  createdDate: "2017-11-17",
  doneDate: "2017-11-18",
},
{
  createdDate: "2017-11-18",
  doneDate: "2017-11-18",
},
{
  createdDate: "2017-11-19",
  doneDate: "2017-11-19",
},
{
  createdDate: "2017-11-19",
  doneDate: "2017-11-19",
},
{
  createdDate: "2017-11-20",
  doneDate: "2017-11-20",
},
{
  createdDate: "2017-11-20",
  doneDate: "2017-11-21",
},
```

I have created an interface :

```
export interface myObject 
{   
  createdDate: Date;   
  doneDate: Date; 
}
```

What I am trying to do is have an table with:

```
Date; created; done
2017-11-17;3;2
2017-11-18;1;2
2017-11-19;2;2
2017-11-20;2;1
2017-11-21;0;1
```

I would appreciate any help, even if it like showing me where I can document myself to do this.

Comment: Show us the reduce methods you have attempted so far, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your example data is saved in the arr variable.

```
export interface Timestamp {
 createdDate: string;
 doneDate: string;
}

const createdCount = arr.reduce((acc: any, { createdDate }): Timestamp => {
  acc[createdDate] = acc[createdDate] === undefined ? 1 : acc[createdDate] + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const doneCount = arr.reduce((acc: any, { doneDate }): Timestamp => {
  acc[doneDate] = acc[doneDate] === undefined ? 1 : acc[doneDate] + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const dates = arr.reduce((acc: any, { createdDate, doneDate }) => {
  return Array.from(new Set([...acc, createdDate, doneDate]));
}, []);

const result = dates.reduce((acc: any, date) => {
  acc[date] = {
    created: createdCount[date] || 0,
    done: doneCount[date] || 0,
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

[image]

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6uj4t)

Comment: I'll try it asap.. thanks for taking time to answer me...on a sunday... :)

Comment: Hi, I have a question, how do I extract this for a chart data,

Example : 

x-axis [2017-11-17,2017-11-18,...]
created[3,1,2,2,0,...]
done[2,2,2,1,1,....]

Sorry for this noob question

Answer (score 0):

that is not making sense to me.

you can have a key in a json file which is an array of object:

```
{
  "arrayOdOobjects": [
    {
      "createdDate": "2017-11-17",
      "doneDate": "2017-11-17"
    },
    {
      "createdDate": "2017-11-17",
      "doneDate": "2017-11-17"
    },
    {
      "createdDate": "2017-11-17",
      "doneDate": "2017-11-18"
    },
    {
       "createdDate": "2017-11-18",
       "doneDate": "2017-11-18"
    },
    {
       "createdDate": "2017-11-19",
       "doneDate": "2017-11-19"
    },

  ]
}
```

then you can grab the json by importing in the .ts component file:

`var json = require('./arrayofobjects.json');`

then iterate it (there is other ways but I think this is the visually more simple):

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  jsonArray = json.arrayOfObjects;
  array = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonArray.forEach(obj => {
      this.array.push([new Date(), obj.createdDate, obj.doneDate]);
    });

    console.log(this.array)
  }
}
```

Or I completely miss interpreted the question? ^^
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for helpin, the answer below seems to be what I need.. I'll look into it ...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like this
and your JSON data will satisfy data format for Amcharts without any need to change

sample data -

`{
      "date1": "2014-12-02",
      "y1": "2014-12-02 06:24"
    }, {
      "date1": "2014-12-04",
      "y1": "2014-12-02 06:39"
    }, {
      "date1": "2014-12-06",
      "y1": "2014-12-02 07:05"
    }, {
      "date1": "2014-12-08",
      "y1": "2014-12-02 08:15"
    }, {
      "date1": "2014-12-09",
      "y1": "2014-12-02 08:56"
    }`

[Please check Amcharts example here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/date-based-xy-chart-time-based-y-axis/)